Crystal Reports Sql joins
All,
I've had some great help on previous issues with this report from "https://stackoverflow.com/users/1734722/milletsoftware".
However, as is nearly always the case, as you get past one issue the machine throughs up another.
Well here is the latest issue : Please see code below :
SELECT
"OINV"."DocNum",
"OINV"."DocDate",
"OINV"."CardName",
"INV1"."Dscription",
"OINV"."CardCode",
"OINV"."BPLName",
"INV1"."LineTotal",
"INV1"."GTotal",
"INV1"."InvQty",
"OINV"."VatSum",
"INV1"."LineVat",
"INV1"."Rate",
"INV1"."Quantity",
"INV1"."VatPrcnt",
"INV1"."Price",
"OINV"."DocEntry",
"INV1"."PriceAfVAT",
"INV1"."Width1",
"INV1"."Width2",
"OACT"."AcctCode",
"OACT"."AcctName",
"OINV"."LicTradNum",
"OINV"."Pindicator",
"INV1"."Itemcode",
"INV1"."ItemType",
"INV1"."AcctCode",
"OINV"."BPLId"
FROM   ("DATABASE"."dbo"."OACT" "OACT" INNER JOIN "DATABASE"."dbo"."INV1" "INV1" ON "OACT"."AcctCode"="INV1"."AcctCode") INNER JOIN "DATABASE"."dbo"."OINV" "OINV" ON "INV1"."DocEntry"="OINV"."DocEntry"
UNION
SELECT
"OCSI"."DocNum",
"OCSI"."DocDate",
"OCSI"."CardName",
"CSI1"."Dscription",
"OCSI"."CardCode",
"OCSI"."BPLName",
"CSI1"."LineTotal",
"CSI1"."GTotal",
"CSI1"."InvQty",
"OCSI"."VatSum",
"CSI1"."LineVat",
"CSI1"."Rate",
"CSI1"."Quantity",
"CSI1"."VatPrcnt",
"CSI1"."Price",
"OCSI"."DocEntry",
"CSI1"."PriceAfVAT",
"CSI1"."Width1",
"CSI1"."Width2",
"OACT"."AcctCode",
"OACT"."AcctName",
"OCSI"."LicTradNum",
"OCSI"."Pindicator",
"CSI1"."Itemcode",
"CSI1"."ItemType",
"CSI1"."AcctCode",
"OCSI"."BPLId"
FROM   ("DATABASE"."dbo"."OCSI" "OCSI" INNER JOIN "DATABASE"."dbo"."CSI1" "CSI1" ON "OCSI"."DocEntry"="CSI1"."DocEntry") INNER JOIN "DATABASE"."dbo"."OACT" "OACT" ON "CSI1"."AcctCode"="OACT"."AcctCode"
UNION
SELECT
"ORIN"."DocNum",
"ORIN"."DocDate",
"ORIN"."CardName",
"RIN1"."Dscription",
"ORIN"."CardCode",
"ORIN"."BPLName",
"RIN1"."LineTotal"*-1,
"RIN1"."GTotal",
"RIN1"."InvQty",
"ORIN"."VatSum",
"RIN1"."LineVat",
"RIN1"."Rate",
"RIN1"."Quantity",
"RIN1"."VatPrcnt",
"RIN1"."Price",
"ORIN"."DocEntry",
"RIN1"."PriceAfVAT",
"RIN1"."Width1",
"RIN1"."Width2",
"OACT"."AcctCode",
"OACT"."AcctName",
"ORIN"."LicTradNum",
"ORIN"."Pindicator",
"RIN1"."Itemcode",
"RIN1"."ItemType",
"RIN1"."AcctCode",
"ORIN"."BPLId"
FROM   ("DATABASE"."dbo"."ORIN" "ORIN" INNER JOIN "DATABASE"."dbo"."RIN1" "RIN1" ON "ORIN"."DocEntry"="RIN1"."DocEntry") INNER JOIN "DATABASE"."dbo"."OACT" "OACT" ON "RIN1"."AcctCode"="OACT"."AcctCode"
UNION ALL
SELECT
"_PM_BGT_CNT"."LineId"[Budget],
"_PM_BGT_CNT"."U_EndDate",
"_PM_BGT_CNT"."U_CardName",
"_PM_BGT_CNT"."U_ItemCode",
"_PM_BGT_CNT"."U_CardCode",
"_PM_BGT_CNT"."U_Comments",
"_PM_BGT_CNT"."U_M01Amnt",
"_PM_BGT_CNT"."U_M02Amnt",
"_PM_BGT_CNT"."U_M03Amnt",
"_PM_BGT_CNT"."U_M04Amnt",
"_PM_BGT_CNT"."U_M05Amnt",
"_PM_BGT_CNT"."U_M06Amnt",
"_PM_BGT_CNT"."U_M07Amnt",
"_PM_BGT_CNT"."U_M08Amnt",
"_PM_BGT_CNT"."U_M09Amnt",
"_PM_BGT_CNT"."U_M10Amnt",
"_PM_BGT_CNT"."U_M11Amnt",
"_PM_BGT_CNT"."U_M12Amnt",
"_PM_BGT_CNT"."U_YearAmnt",
"_PM_BGT_CNT"."U_CntId",
"_PM_BGT_CNT"."U_ItemType",
"_PM_BGT_CNT"."U_Location",
"_PM_BGT_CNT"."U_LocId",
"_PM_BGT_CNT"."U_SalesAcc",
"_PM_OBGT"."U_Year",
"_PM_OBGT"."U_Type",
"_PM_OBGT"."U_BPLId"
FROM   ("DATABASE"."dbo"."@PM_BGT_CNT" "_PM_BGT_CNT" INNER JOIN "DATABASE"."dbo"."OACT" "OACT" ON "_PM_BGT_CNT"."U_SalesAcc"="OACT"."AcctCode") INNER JOIN "DATABASE"."dbo"."@PM_OBGT" "_PM_OBGT" ON "_PM_BGT_CNT"."DocEntry"="_PM_OBGT"."DocEntry"
THE ISSUE
In Crystal Reports the "Field Explorer - Database Fields - Command Field List" dose not show the fields for table nest 4 (in italics above) and as can be seen in the screenshot below:
Crystal Report Screenshot
May be a join issue! May be something else!
HELP! PLEASE!
Many thanks in advance.
Simon.
Tried some different joins but the database crashed with some of them, kind off worked with others but watching paint dry is faster!

UNION statement do not add more columns to the previous result sets. Instead, they append more rows, using the column names specifies in the 1st result set.

So how can I fix it? The first 3 nests are fine as all the fields in each of the tables is the same as in the other tables. Its nest 4 where my issue lies. I need all the columns in 4 along with the columns in the first nest of tables to complete my report. The first three nest of tables are AR invoices, AR credit memos and the third AR correction invoices, the idea is to compare them monthly to the budget which is nest 4. I need the first 3 as is and need some way of bring in 4 to the report. May be something like an external join. I'll give any further details required, just ask! Thanks!

Keep the UNION operation for the 3 first statements.
Join the result of that UNION to the Budget table.
Here is a discussion of how to mix UNION operations with a JOIN:
Using SQL JOIN and UNION together

My friend .. I tried it, but no joy! This one has me beat! Needed it for Monday so as not to get canned, but to impress a little . However there's a simple report they've requested, so I'll give them that and live another day. So it's 3am here in the Emerald Isle but thanks you have been a great help, good night god bless .. Simon.
